# C# int32 literal can only be stored in long data type

Tags: c#, variable-assignment, literals, unsigned-integer

Im preparing for a very tricky c# exam and this question popped up while doing so.
I have the following code:

```
 uint zzz = -12u;
```

`-12u` is recognized as `System.Uint32` literal but it can only be stored in variable of type `long`. Why is that ?

Comment: Do you know what the `u` stands for?

Comment: I'm guessing because an unsigned int is supposed to be unsigned?

Comment: Hint: "-12u is recognized as System.Uint32" is incorrect. It would be correct to say "12u is recognized as System.Uint32".

Comment: unsigned means that only non-negative values are allowed. -12 is simply not representable in an uint variable

Comment: I know what the u stands for, Im trying some unlikely situations. U stands for unsigned, while -12 is obviously negative number. However the binary representation of -12, when converted to a uint decimal number can fit perfectly in uint. But for some reason I cant store that value in a variable of type uint.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What it is doing is taking the unsigned int 12 and trying to convert it into a negative value (the `-`) which requires a conversion to a type that can handle negative numbers as an unsigned int cannot.

Because it is an unsigned int it has possible values outside the range of int, so conversion to a long is required.

Comment: Yup; if you look at the [integer literal spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674.aspx) you can see that the minus sign isn't part of the literal, so it's creating a `uint` and then having to widen it to `long` when negating it.

Answer (score 0):

because `u`  is    for unsigned   int
for handling -ve sign it converting it into Long data type
-12u is a signed int data type & for storing it in `unsigned` type it uses `long` data type